# What archives is the bq Ubuntu Phone on?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

So, I'm messing with my bq ubuntu phone, trying to [install libreoffice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfMLzlki9XE) but I hit a roadblock. Libreoffice isn't in the archives!

What archives is the Ubuntu phone on? Can I "upgrade" to archives containing libreoffice?

This is /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09 main restricted
deb-src http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09 main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09-updates main restricted
deb-src http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09 universe
deb-src http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09 universe
deb http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09-updates universe
deb-src http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09-backports main restricted universe
# deb-src http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09-backports main restricted universe

deb http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09-security main restricted
deb-src http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09-security main restricted
deb http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09-security universe
deb-src http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09-security universe
# deb http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09-security multiverse
# deb-src http://derived.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu-rtm/ 14.09-security multiverse
```

Below the output of searching apt for libreoffice:

```
 apt-cache search libreoffice
hunspell-ru - Russian dictionary for hunspell
hyphen-af - Afrikaans hyphenation patterns for LibreOffice
hyphen-ca - Catalan hyphenation patterns for LibreOffice
hyphen-de - German hyphenation patterns for LibreOffice
hyphen-fr - French hyphenation patterns for LibreOffice
hyphen-hr - Croatian hyphenation pattern for LibreOffice
hyphen-hu - Hungarian hyphenation patterns for LibreOffice
hyphen-it - Italian hyphenation patterns for LibreOffice
hyphen-ro - Romanian hyphenation patterns for LibreOffice
hyphen-sl - Slovenian hyphenation patterns for LibreOffice
hyphen-sr - Serbian (Cyrillic) hyphenation patterns for LibreOffice
hyphen-sv - Swedish hyphenation patterns for LibreOffice
hyphen-zu - Zulu hyphenation patterns for LibreOffice
myspell-af - Afrikaans dictionary for myspell
myspell-ca - Catalan dictionary for myspell
myspell-en-gb - English_british dictionary for myspell
myspell-en-us - English_american dictionary for myspell
myspell-en-za - English_southafrican dictionary for myspell
myspell-hr - Croatian dictionary for myspell
myspell-it - Italian dictionary for myspell
myspell-sw - Swahili dictionary for myspell
myspell-th - Thai dictionary for myspell
mythes-ca - Catalan Thesaurus for LibreOffice
mythes-cs - Czech Thesaurus for LibreOffice
mythes-en-us - English Thesaurus for LibreOffice
mythes-fr - French Thesaurus for LibreOffice
mythes-hu - Hungarian Thesaurus for LibreOffice
mythes-ne - Nepali Thesaurus for LibreOffice
mythes-ro - Romanian Thesaurus for LibreOffice
mythes-ru - Russian Thesaurus for LibreOffice
mythes-sk - Slovak Thesaurus for LibreOffice/OpenOffice.org
unity-scope-home - Home scope that aggregates results from multiple scopes
```

Comment: Is the meta package `libreoffice` missing or is `libreoffice-writer` missing? Seems like `libreoffice-writer` is indeed built for armhf.

Comment: @JonasG.Drange, both are missing. I added the output of `apt-cache search libreoffice` to my post

Comment: Right, then you'll need to add vivid/main, but there's no guarantee that your device will function as expected after adding that repository.

Comment: Do NOT add vivid/main to a shipping phone. The phone ships with rtm-14.09 which is a derivative of utopic, not vivid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a derivative of Utopic taken back in August last year. The following email details this. https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2014-June/002878.html

```
"We will then have an "ubuntu-phone" (name TBD) distribution in
Launchpad with a series named something like "rtm-14.09", and will
land changes for RTM there, allowing other parts of Ubuntu to move on
without risk of breaking phone images. "
```

So the archive used by the phone is a derivative of the archive used around the time of the Ubuntu desktop 14.10.

More details at https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg09377.html

```
"The point of this approach is to make sure that we're completely
confident in the infrastructure and have no unforeseen glitches, without
imposing an undue load on engineering teams while lots of people are
still busy with significant feature development."
```

Comment: So if I read this correctly, the plan is to move to the normal Ubuntu archives after a while? And installing 14.10 arm packages would be more or less doable?

Comment: Yeah, we'll move to vivid soon. But there are ongoing discussions about what to do when the next device comes along, and whether we fork again.